# Why Route does not change after async function call in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have a code pattern that I know is not going to work but I am not able to reason it out.

```
const MyComponent=()=>{
  const history = useHistory();

  function sleep(ms) {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
   
  async function onClickHandler(){
    await sleep(2000)
    history.push("/newRoute");
  }
  
  return (
    <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Click Me!!</button>
  )
}
```

For code above, when you click the button, the function **should** await for 2 sec and then transition to newRoute.

**This does not happen.** Nothing happens when you click the button. I am not sure I understand the reason behind it. Ideally await should resolve after 2 sec and history.push should be called. Why is it not getting called?

Comment: have you tried `console.log` instead of `history.push`? Just to prove that it's not broken for other reasons?

Comment: Please add this: import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

Comment: I didn't observe any bug in the given code. So, I tried it on codesandbox.io and it is executing without any issue. Probably you have done something wrong in defining the switch case for routes.  Please share your whole code. 

[Codesandbox url](https://codesandbox.io/s/68012570-kx6i5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yeah I see. Maybe its bug in another file. Let me have a look. Thanks @priyansh-gaharana

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: OP here:
The above question does not contain any bug. There was a bug in another file. Please follow @priyansh-gaharana answer in the comment for codesandbox url